# Java Code is not working, as it says that the command execution failed

Tags: java

Hello I was trying to create a Calculator program using OOP in Java, however as soon as I was done doing the code, I was hit with a sort of compilation error as my code does not run. Whenever I check the IDE it does not have any problems with the main body of the code, I'd like some help on how to fix this error

Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.oopcalculator.OOPCalculator
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.oopcalculator.OOPCalculator
Command execution failed.

P.S I am using the Netbeans IDE, and I was using the maven plugin
Here is the code:

```
package com.mycompany.oopcalculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator{
    double a;
    double b;
    
    public double getA(){
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(double a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    public double getB(){
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(double b){
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void Add(double a, double b){
         double c;
         c = getA() + getB();
         System.out.println("The Sum of Your 2 Chosen Numbers is: " + c);
    }
    public void Subtract(double a, double b){
        double c;
        c = getA() - getB();
        System.out.println("The Difference of Your 2 Chosen Numbers is: " + c);
    }
    public void Divide(double a, double b){
        double c;
        c = getA() / getB();
        System.out.println("The Quotient of Your 2 Chosen Numbers is: " + c);
    }
    public void Multiply(double a, double b){
        double c;
        c = getA() * getB();
        System.out.println("The Product of Your 2 Chosen Numbers is: " + c);
    }
    public void Power(double a, double b){
        double c = Math.pow(getA(),getB());
        System.out.println("The Power of Your Chosen Number is: " + c);
    }
    public void NthRoot(double a, double b){
        double c = Math.pow(getA(), 1.0 / getB());
        c = Math.pow(Math.round(c), getB());
        System.out.println("The " + getB() + "th Root of Your Chosen Number is: " + c);
}
public class OOPCalculator {
        public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Calculator Program");
        System.out.println("Please Choose Which Method You Want to Use: a - Add, b - Subtract, c - Multiply, d - Divide, e - Power, f - NthRoot");
        String method = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.setA(scan.nextDouble());
        calc.setB(scan.nextDouble());
        scan.nextLine();
        switch (method){
            case "a":
                calc.Add(calc.getA(), calc.getB());
                break;
            case "b":
                calc.Subtract(calc.getA(), calc.getB());
                break;
            case "c":
                calc.Multiply(calc.getA(), calc.getB());
                break;
            case "d":
                calc.Divide(calc.getA(), calc.getB());
                break;
            case "e":
                calc.Power(calc.getA(), calc.getB());
                break;
            case "f":
                calc.NthRoot(calc.getA(), calc.getB());
                break;
                
            default:
                System.out.println("The Method is Invalid Please Try Again");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any possible answers as I am still new to coding :)

I tried to double check each part of the code, and as I checked so far there are no problems, I expected the code to work normally however it led to a compilation error which I don't know how to solve.

Comment: you don't need to have another class `OOPCalculator` to add the main method, just add it at the end of the `Calculator` class or create a new file for `OOPCalculator` class

Comment: There is a `src/main/java/com/mycompany/oopcalculator/OOPCalculator.java`?

Comment: May I ask if you can explain further? 
(I apologize as I am still very very new to coding in general as well as java)

Comment: The problem is that the class OOPCalculator is present inside the class Calculator, which is not correct. In Java, only one public class is allowed per file, and the file name should match the name of the public class. In your case, it seems that OOPCalculator is declared inside the Calculator class, which is not allowed. Move the OOPCalculator class to a separate file and define your main function there.

Comment: @jarus a class inside another class *is* allowed, but they can't expect to be able to run the inner class as if it was toplevel. And your assumption about the file name is probably correct too.

Comment: “done doing the code, I was hit with a sort of compilation error” — Compile early, compile often. Don’t wait.

Comment: Thank you for the responses as well as the tips! I'd like to clarify if my understanding is correct, so does that mean I would need to have 2 files, 1 for the public class OOPCalculator and 1 for the class Calculator? @jarus

Comment: @Huntbruh - Yes, that is correct. You can also have both classes in the same file, but make sure to place the OOPCalculator class outside of the Calculator class and the file should be named after the OOPCalculator class.

Comment: Thank you so much! The both classes in the same file answer was just what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

Your curly brackets are misplaced. In the sample code that you have provided, the class `OOPCalculator` is inside the class `Calculator` and that is why the Java compiler is not able to find it.

Take it out of the `Calculator` class and your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by TDivyanshu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77895574/642706) is correct. Each public class must be in its own file.

Below is my revised version of your code. Issues addressed in my revisions:

- By convention, Java method names start with a lowercase letter. So, `divide`, not `Divide`.
- An evolving convention is to avoid ALL-CAPS in a class name. If an acronym is well-known enough to be used within a name, treat it like any other word with camelCase. So, `OopCalculator`. (Even better would be a more descriptive name such as `CalculatorApp`.)
- Add `final` to your parameters to ensure the passed values are not inadvertently modified by your code.
- Prompt your user for each input. Don't leave them hanging.
- Group your code logically. Notice how I establish our necessary resources `Scanner` and `Calculator` up top. Only after that do I start the user-interface code.

### One `.java` file per public class

Put the `Calculator` class in a file named `Calculator.java`.

```java
package work.basil.example.calculating;

class Calculator
{
    private double a;
    private double b;

    public double getA ( )
    {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA ( final double a )
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public double getB ( )
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB ( final double b )
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void add ( final double a , final double b )
    {
        double c;
        c = getA ( ) + getB ( );
        System.out.println ( "The Sum of Your 2 Chosen Numbers is: " + c );
    }

    public void subtract ( final double a , final double b )
    {
        double c;
        c = getA ( ) - getB ( );
        System.out.println ( "The Difference of Your 2 Chosen Numbers is: " + c );
    }

    public void divide ( final double a , final double b )
    {
        double c;
        c = getA ( ) / getB ( );
        System.out.println ( "The Quotient of Your 2 Chosen Numbers is: " + c );
    }

    public void multiply ( final double a , final double b )
    {
        double c;
        c = getA ( ) * getB ( );
        System.out.println ( "The Product of Your 2 Chosen Numbers is: " + c );
    }

    public void power ( final double a , final double b )
    {
        double c = Math.pow ( getA ( ) , getB ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "The Power of Your Chosen Number is: " + c );
    }

    public void nthRoot ( final double a , final double b )
    {
        double c = Math.pow ( getA ( ) , 1.0 / getB ( ) );
        c = Math.pow ( Math.round ( c ) , getB ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "The " + getB ( ) + "th Root of Your Chosen Number is: " + c );
    }
}
```

Put the `OopCalculator` class in a file name `OopCalculator.java`.

```java
package work.basil.example.calculating;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class OopCalculator
{
    public static void main ( final String[] args )
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );
        Calculator calc = new Calculator ( );

        System.out.println ( "Welcome to the Calculator Program" );
        System.out.println ( "Please Choose Which Method You Want to Use: a - Add, b - Subtract, c - Multiply, d - Divide, e - Power, f - NthRoot" );
        String method = scan.nextLine ( ).toLowerCase ( );
        System.out.println ( "Enter number: " );
        calc.setA ( scan.nextDouble ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "Enter number: " );
        calc.setB ( scan.nextDouble ( ) );
        scan.nextLine ( );
        switch ( method )
        {
            case "a":
                calc.add ( calc.getA ( ) , calc.getB ( ) );
                break;
            case "b":
                calc.subtract ( calc.getA ( ) , calc.getB ( ) );
                break;
            case "c":
                calc.multiply ( calc.getA ( ) , calc.getB ( ) );
                break;
            case "d":
                calc.divide ( calc.getA ( ) , calc.getB ( ) );
                break;
            case "e":
                calc.power ( calc.getA ( ) , calc.getB ( ) );
                break;
            case "f":
                calc.nthRoot ( calc.getA ( ) , calc.getB ( ) );
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println ( "The Method is Invalid. Please Try Again." );
        }
    }
}
```

You said:

> done doing the code, I was hit with a sort of compilation error

**Compile early, compile often.** After every bit of code added, compile. After every thought is implemented, run the app too.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should check whether the code is saved properly in  the package as i copied and compiled your program and it compiled successfully.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW3j4.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).